# JavaScript button to call the Apex method is not working

Tags: apex, javascript-remoting

I have an existing JavaScript button that calls Apex, and it works fine.  I then want to add a second parameter to the method, but for some reason it isn't working. Is there something else I need to do?

The code below works:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")} 

var response = sforce.apex.execute("IFE/IFE_ButtonMethods", "createIQuoteCall", {oppID:"{!Opportunity.Id}"});
```

The Apex method that goes with it:

```
webservice static string createIQuoteCall(String oppID)
{
```

This following does not work:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")} 

var response = sforce.apex.execute("IFE/IFE_ButtonMethods", "createIQuoteAcc", {oppID:"{!Opportunity.Id}"}, {accId:"{!Opportunity.AccountId}"});
```

The Apex method that goes with it:

```
webservice static string createIQuoteAcc(String oppID, String accId)
{
```

The error I get is:

> onSuccess not defined in the callback.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you up the verison to 30.0 for both the scripts and try? And also `apex.execute` call is a synchronous callout not sure why you're getting the `callback` error..

Comment: @theGreatDanton I just did it and got the same error.  I have no idea.  It doesn't make sense to me... that the first one works but not the second.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You should collect all parameters within one `{...}` block:

```
sforce.apex.execute("IFE/IFE_ButtonMethods", 
                    "createIQuoteAcc",  
                    {oppID:"{!Opportunity.Id}", accId:"{!Opportunity.AccountId}"});
```

Comment: I was about to answer this, you beat me to it :)

Comment: Gah I can't believe I didn't think of trying it like that.  Thanks!

Comment: @theGreatDanton Hehe :) Next time then!

Comment: @dphil It was my first syntax error too, as I've started with ajax toolkit.